# Duplicate recursive logic on voucherNo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

How to make recursive logic in code handleDuplicate. So, for example, a duplicate of the initial voucherNo. CALC/2023/06/0001 has been made and duplicated with 4 voucherNo calculators with an example, namely:
CALC/2023/06/0001(1)
CALC/2023/06/0001(2)
CALC/2023/06/0001(3)
CALC/2023/06/0001(4)
so the picture is when CALC/2023/06/0001(3) is deleted, CALC/2023/06/0001(2) can be duplicated again and the resulting duplicate becomes CALC/2023/06/0001(3).

- code in FormWrapper -
  {(parseInt(id) !== 0 && statusKhusus === false) && (
  <button type="button" className="btn btn-duplicate mr-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" onClick={(e) => handleDuplicate(e)}>
  Duplicate

  )}

  ```
                  {(parseInt(id) !== 0 && statusKhusus === true) && (
                    <span></span>
                  )}
  ```
- code in CalculatorForm -

> ```
> const handleDuplicate = () => {
>         swal({
>             title: 'Confirmation',
>             text: 'Are you sure want to duplicate this data?',
>             icon: 'warning',
>             buttons: [true, 'Duplicate'],
>         }).then((succeed) => {
>
>             if (succeed) {
>                 //const newFormData = { ...formData };
>                 let newFormData = { ...formData }
>                 let voucherNo = newFormData.voucherNo;
>                 let increment = 1;
>                 const regex = /\((\d+)\)$/;
>
>                 newFormData.id = 0;
>                 newFormData.calculatorDetails = newFormData.calculatorDetails.map((item) => {
>                     const detail = { ...item, id: 0 };
>                     return detail;
>                 });
>
>                 newFormData.calculatorApprovals = [];
>                 newFormData.calculatorHistories = [];
>
>                 const match = voucherNo.match(regex);
>                 if (match) {
>                     increment = parseInt(match[1]) + 1;
>                     voucherNo = voucherNo.replace(regex, '');
>                 }
>
>                 newFormData.voucherNo = `${voucherNo}(${increment})`;
>                 addData({ url, body: newFormData }).then((res) => {
>                     navigate(`${path}/${res.data.id}/edit`);
>                 });
>
>                 formData.statusKhusus = true;
>                 editData({ url, body: formData }).then((obj) => {
>                     navigate(`${path}/${obj.data.id}/edit`);
>                 })
>             }
>         });
>     };
>
> <div className="form-group col-sm-6">
>                         <label>Calculation #</label>
>                         <input id="calculationInput" className="form-control" type="text" name="voucherNo"
> ```
>
> value={formData.voucherNo} onChange={isCountReverse ? (e) =>
> onCountReverseChange(e) : (e) => onChange(e)} readOnly />